# Does the NEAT alogrithm disable genes randomly?

Tags: neat

It is not mentioned in the original paper, if genes can be disabled randomly. They only mention that the connection gene is disabled, when a node is inserted in it's place. Is it the case, that genes can be disabled randomly as well?